# Dart unit test framework's `expect` does not seem to work properly

Tags: unit-testing, dart

Here is an object's de to compare `MapState`:

```
class MapState {
  final Coordinate currentCoordinate;
  final Iterable<Coordinate> markers;

  MapState(this.currentCoordinate, this.markers);

  MapState.empty()
      : this.currentCoordinate = null,
        this.markers = [];

  MapState.withCoordinate(this.currentCoordinate) : this.markers = [];

  MapState.withMarkers(this.markers) : this.currentCoordinate = null;

  MapState newCoordinate(final Coordinate coordinate) =>
      MapState(coordinate, this.markers);

  MapState newMarkersSet(final Iterable<Coordinate> markers) =>
      MapState(this.currentCoordinate, markers);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
          other is MapState &&
              runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
              currentCoordinate == other.currentCoordinate &&
              markers == other.markers;

  @override
  int get hashCode =>
      currentCoordinate.hashCode ^
      markers.hashCode;

}
```

Here is the unit-test:

```
test('init, Observer should receive an empty state as a first state',
  () {
    expect(MapState.empty(), MapState.empty());
  });
```

Result (failure, of course):

> Expected: Instance of 'MapState'
>
> Actual: Instance of 'MapState'
>
> package:test_api                                   expect
>
> package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart 196:3  expect
>
> test/application/map_bloc_test.dart 25:5           main.

I simplified the primal test to this to track the error down, so don't get confused by the senseless of the unit-test.

Changing `expect(MapState.empty(), MapState.empty());` to `expect(1, 1);` helps, but I can't get it working with my objects.

Also, here is my imports block:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:taxi/application/map_bloc.dart';
import 'package:taxi/domain/map.dart';
```

P.S.: strangely, but changing `this.markers = []` to `this.markers = const []` helps. Wut??? Anyway, `expect([], []);` works. That just doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test fails because `[] == []` is `false` in Dart. You can use the [collection package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/collection) to handle collection equality.

Comment: That is just supreme nonsense. Why `expect([], []);` passes and `expect(true, [] == []);` doesn't? x.x

Comment: Because `expect` handles collections and compare them element by element.

Comment: Thing that isn't even mentioned in the documentation of the `expect` method...
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin It is documented, albeit indirectly and not the most clearly. [`expect`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/test_api/latest/test_api/expect.html) states: "`matcher` can be a value in which case it will be wrapped in an [equals](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/matcher/latest/matcher/equals.html) matcher." The documentation for the `equals` matcher says: "For `Iterables` and `Maps`, this will recursively match the elements."

Answer (score 0):

In my case [Equitable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) helped. Applying to Andrey's case MapState class should have extended Equatable.